# Pip installer error

Tags: python, pip, pyautogui

I am trying to install `PyAutoGUI` but every time i try i get the error message

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>C:\Users\nicho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\pip install PyAutoGUI
Collecting PyAutoGUI
  Using cached PyAutoGUI-0.9.33.zip
Collecting pymsgbox (from PyAutoGUI)
  Using cached PyMsgBox-1.0.3.zip
Collecting PyTweening>=1.0.1 (from PyAutoGUI)
  Using cached PyTweening-1.0.3.zip
Collecting Pillow (from PyAutoGUI)
  Using cached Pillow-3.1.1-cp35-none-win32.whl
Collecting pyscreeze (from PyAutoGUI)
  Using cached PyScreeze-0.1.8.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\nicho\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-jt08_ns2\pyscreeze\setup.py", line 6, in <module>
        version=__import__('pyscreeze').__version__,
      File "c:\users\nicho\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-jt08_ns2\pyscreeze\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
        from PIL import Image
    ImportError: No module named 'PIL'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\nicho\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-jt08_ns2\pyscreeze
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: it seems you not install `PIL` module, try to install `Pillow` using command `pip install Pillow`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install the `Python Image Library(PIL)`, using the command:

```
sudo pip install PIL --allow-external PIL --allow-unverified PIL
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the virtual environment for python packages. It is really user friendly in pycharm for example and you can test out packages before using up hard drive space.

Comment: I have a 2TB hard drive i don't care about disk space